# Getting arguments for any callable object?

Tags: python, callable-object

I am interested in obtaining a general way to obtain a list of arguments and keyword arguments taken by a callable Python object. This is straight-forward for functions with the `inspect.getargspec` function, for example:

```
import inspect
from functools import partial

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs

print(inspect.getargspec(foo))
>>ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)

def bar(*args):
    return args

print(inspect.getargspec(bar))
>>ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

However, this fails in cases such as these:

```
partial_function = partial(foo, kwarg="value")

inspect.getargspec(partial_function)
>>TypeError: <functools.partial object at 0x11748bc58> is not a Python function

class Foo(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return args, kwargs

foo_instance = Foo()

inspect.getargspec(foo_instance)
>>TypeError: <__main__.Foo object at 0x116c13ed0> is not a Python function

inspect.getargspec(zip)
>>TypeError: <built-in function zip> is not a Python function
```

Note, that there are ways to obtain the arguments for the partial function and for the callable object, i.e:

```
inspect.getargspec(partial_function.func)
>>ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)

inspect.getargspec(foo_instance.__call__)
>>ArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)
```

but I would like a more general way of obtaining these results, if at all possible.

Comment: oh wait, are you using python 2?

Comment: Ahh yes i am using python 2. Great to know that python 3 has such great support for getting this info though.

Answer (score 7):

All these can be handled by using the [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) helper function which, as stated in its docs:

> Accepts a wide range of python callables, from plain functions and classes to `functools.partial()` objects.

What `signature` does is it takes your callable and constructs a `Signature` object from it:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> s = signature(Foo())  # class as shown in your example
```

with the arguments now lying in the `parameters` mapping attribute for the `Signature` instance:

```
>>> s.parameters
mappingproxy({'args': <Parameter "*args">, 'kwargs': <Parameter "**kwargs">})
```

With a `partial` object, you'd get the corresponding representation:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c): pass
>>> p = partial(foo, c = 30)
>>> signature(p).parameters
<Signature (a, b, *, c=20)>
```

As for built-in functions such as `zip`, this isn't always possible, some of these functions don't expose the appropriate metadata to construct a signature, [from `PEP 362`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#some-functions-may-not-be-introspectable):

> Some functions may not be introspectable in certain implementations of Python. For example, in CPython, built-in functions defined in `C` provide no metadata about their arguments. Adding support for them is out of scope for this PEP.

So, while `zip` isn't the type to expose information about itself, others are, e.g `all`:

```
>>> signature(all)
<Signature (iterable, /)>
```

you'll unfortunately require a `try-except` for these, there's nothing else that can be done.

The cases that the `signature` helper handles are enumerated in the [implementation section of `PEP 362`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#implementation) which introduced it.

In general, `inspect.getargspec` has been deprecated for a while now in Python 3, the suggested approach (if you're using Python 3, that is) is to use  the representation offered via `Signature` objects.

If on Python `2`, I'm pretty sure you can't do it directly with `getargspec`, you should use `getfullargspec` as Anttis' answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

[`getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) also handles partials correctly. It was previously deprecated but was *undeprecated* since it was deemed that it is quite useful for single-source Python 2/3 polyglot code.

Another option is [`signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) which is a bit more complicated.